# ENV variables not being transferred to Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have the following code in my paperclip.rb file:

```
# Paperclip config
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
        :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
        :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
        :region => 'oregon'
      }
    }
```

As you can see I'm using ENV variables to protect the keys. I'm also using an application.yml file to actually store the keys as follows:

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME: "*bucketname"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "*keys here*"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "*keys here*"
```

For some reason though, the keys aren't being transferred to the Paperclip ENV variables and I'm getting a missing keys error when I run migrations that involve paperclip and S3.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edit with errors:

```
AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.39.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:374:in `return_or_raise'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/aws-sdk-1.39.0/lib/aws/core/client.rb:475:in `client_request'
```

Comment: Can you share the errors that you are getting.

Comment: Thanks Kirti, I've added the error, and I know this is the problem because when I've added the keys directly to the paperclip settings it worked. So it's a problem with the ENV variables.

Comment: Are you facing this problem in production environment(heroku) ?

Comment: Hi, no because I am using figaro to transfer the keys in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `Heroku`, you would have to set each of the environment variables by running the following command:

```
$ heroku config:set key ="value"
```

For example:

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME ="your_bucket_name"
```

As you are using `figaro gem`, you get a readymade `figaro` command using which you can set values from your configuration file `application.yml` all at once:

```
$ figaro heroku:set -e production
```

To verify the set variables use the following command which will list all the set environment variables:

```
$ heroku config
```

Refer to [Heroku: Configuration and Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) and [Figaro on Heroku](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro#heroku) for details.

**UPDATE**

In development environment,

Make sure you run `rails generate figaro:install` command which creates a `config/application.yml` file and also adds it to your `.gitignore` file.

Add the configurations in `application.yml`:

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME: "your_bucket_name"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "your_access_key_id"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "your_secret_access_key"
```

Make sure the keys namesin `config.paperclip_defaults` match exactly to the keys specified in `application.yml`
**After this restart the server so the configurations are loaded.**

Comment: Thanks Kirti, I've got it working in production. The issue is in development. Any ideas there?